# How to interfere some text in a html link string in python

Tags: python, html, string

In the company I am working they use the above command to construct a link from a list of data we are holding on a map

```
link=a % firstUpper(b)
```

which produces something like

```
<a href="path/tomyhtml/foo.html">foo</a>
```

I would like to alter the link string and add a title attribute to it so it becomes like

```
<a href="path/tomyhtml/foo.html" title="Some cool title">foo</a>
```

my thought was to alter add the title in 3rd character which looks to be "most" of the times a space, but in my mind is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: It would be useful to know how the `a` format string looks like.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. What are you specifically trying to accomplish? It is unclear to me from your question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what `a, b` in `link=a%firstUpper(b)` look like?

Comment: a,b,c=self.links.linkMap.get(otherObjects[link_idx].getMapKey())

Comment: in the initialization 

link='<a href="%s%s%s%s">%s</a>'

self.linkMap.update({kw.getMapKey():(link  % (self.copdirRef,currentDir,kw.getFileName(),extension,'%s'),kw.getName(),kw.isPrioritized())})

So i end up with a prebuild link I think the soup is the most elegant solution but although it is used in another class i get module cannot get imported. I don't know if I helped or anything..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="path/tomyhtml/foo.html">foo</a>')
soup.a["title"] = "Some cool title"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '<a href="%s" title="%s">foo</a>'

print s % (href_string, title_string)
```